# Paint is going through mask

Tags: weight-painting

Is there a way to prevent the paint going through the selected mask?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

not really. In wheight paint mode you are a assigning wheights to the vertecies of the mesh. what you see between the vertecies is only colored based on the vertecies around it. so if you have a base mesh with not that much geometry and you have a vertex an you have one in the mask and one outside, blender cant do better that  to make a gradient between them.

hte only way to make that effect less pronouced is to give the wheight paint more vertecies to work with.

If its crucial that you have a sharp edge you could copy it ad apply the subsurf modifier i assume you use. Or dependant on your use cas you could also switch to a texture map instead.